# Not able to update API management isntance using powershell

Tags: azure-api-management

Trying to fetch system certificates from API management instance .Then trying to remove the certificate and update the APIM instance .

APIM management instance is in INTERNAL VNET mode.

```
Set-AzContext -Subscription "xxxx"
$apimservice= Get-AzApiManagement -ResourceGroupName "xxxx" -Name "xxxx"
$apimservice.SystemCertificates
$apimservice.SystemCertificates.Clear()



Set-AzApiManagement -InputObject $apimservice



ERROR:
Set-AzApiManagement : 'SubnetResourceId' does not match expected pattern '^/subscriptions/[^/]*/resourceGroups/[^/]*/
providers/Microsoft.(ClassicNetwork|Network)/virtualNetworks/[^/]*/subnets/[^/]*$'.
At line:8 char:1
+ Set-AzApiManagement -InputObject $apimservice
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzApiManagement], ValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ApiManagement.Commands.SetAzureApiManagement
```

Comment: I don't think we can remove the systemcertificate. Can you share any link which you are following that can suggest clearing the systemcertificates ?

Comment: system certificate can fetch you CA signed certificates uploaded by the user ,hence it can be removed. you can refer set-azapimanagement command link from Microsoft

Comment: hmm, can you try to get the detailed log by `$DebugPreference = "Continue"` and run the command again ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking to your script it seems correct.

So far as we have not all the configuration as yours we have tried to reproduce the minimal as we can and it works at our end.
[image]

*Could you please make sure you are using `connect-azaccount` before using the `set-azcontext` .*

*And try to use the latest module of* [**`az PowerShell module`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-8.0.0) as 8.0.

> Set-AzApiManagement : 'SubnetResourceId' does not match expected
> pattern '^/subscriptions/[^/]*/resourceGroups/[^/]*/
> providers/Microsoft.(ClassicNetwork|Network)/virtualNetworks/[^/]*/subnets/[^/]*$'.

For the error:-

*Make sure that you have correctly added your resource group as mentioned in portal*.

For more information please refer the below Links:-

- **MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION**|[***Set-AzApiManagement***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/set-azapimanagement?view=azps-8.0.0#example-1-get-an-api-management-service-and-scale-it-to-premium-and-add-a-region)
- **MS Q&A For Similar error**| [***resourceGroupName' does not match expected pattern'^[-\w._()]+[***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/95899/-new-azwebapp-39resourcegroupname39-does-not-match.html) & [***Getting invalid status code conflict while running New-AzRoleAssignment in powershell***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/650669/getting-invalid-status-code-conflict-while-running.html).

Comment: Is this issue resolved? I am using same command to setup the custom domain for APIM and getting same error.